# Best way to handle multiple change streams with SignalR

Tags: angular, mongodb, .net-core, signalr, changestream

I have a .NET Core application that using MongoDB with change streams to retrieve database modifications. Depending on the retrieved documents, a MongoDB query is executed to count the number of documents per client based on their status. The query result is stored in the cache (`IMemoryCache`) so that upon the next database modification, I can retrieve the cached result and update it based on the modifications from the next document.
I use the cache to avoid pooling database all the time.

A message containing the number of documents per client and status is sent using SignalR. An Angular application connected to the hub receives the message and displays it in a grid.

It’s working, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler method to implement than using the cache. Could you provide any advice on whether using the cache is a good solution or if there's a more straightforward approach?

Thank you for your guidance.